# Increase runtime: batteries in parallel -> buck || batteries in series -> boost

Tags: solar-cell, buck-boost

I have 18650 batteries, I created 4S packs with 6P in each.

I have a 12 V 2 A solar panel and I want to use this panel to charge them ( i know I need a charge controller and I must balance charge them )

My main question is:

I have two 5 V devices (Arduino and a power bank charger) that I want to power up with these batteries.

I have two 12 V LED strips each drawing ca 1 A.

Should I put all these 24 batteries in parallel to get my 5 V and use a boost for 12 V or use my current 4S6P and step down to 5 V?

Which setup will give me more runtime?

Having 24P will have an easier charging circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that having 24 batteries in parallel gives you an easier charging circuit and that is true but, it's also a technical compromise in that you cannot ensure charge current is balanced to all 24 parallel batteries equally. Having the batteries in series means that you **can** make a much better job of charge current balancing the batteries but, it does have more complication.

Therefore, my preference is "series connected" because it brings an improved level of security in charging the batteries. Also, a buck regulator that is used to step-down to a lower voltage, provides slightly better efficiency than using a boost regulator to step-up voltage (for the same circuit complexity). Clearly using a synchronous regulation is more efficient than using a non-synchronous circuit too (because you don't lose power in "the diode").

If you decided on a parallel arrangement I would prefer to have independent parallel strings of series-connected batteries so that you could properly charge balance each cell in each string. This of course means a charge balance circuit for each cell but, it's still my preference.

> *Which setup will give me more runtime?*

Well there won't be much difference in either I suspect so, it boils down to which set-up can produce the run-time but also, produce that run-time reliably time and time again.

Comment: I personally prefer the series arrangement, because stepping down is much more efficient, but would it give me the same runtime as 24P?

Comment: I was in the process of addressing that! @far2005

Comment: Thank you, based on w=pv with +/- 10%  I should get the same amount of runtime if I use 4S6P and step down vs 24P and step up. I can't find a 24cell balance charger anywhere and you don't recommend 6P charge correct?

Comment: my 4S6P pack is already made, i'm kind of stuck with this design, Can i charge each cell individually while they are in a parallel pack?

Comment: If they are physically wired to each other then you can't without interrupting that wiring.